# Is there a way to say "use the current font weight" without making it lighter/bolder?

Tags: css, fonts

The `font-weight` property supports numeric values ranging from 100 to 900 inclusive, and keyword values such as `normal` corresponding to 400 and `bold` corresponding to 700.

There's also the `bolder` and `lighter` values, which make an element's font weight one step bolder or lighter than the current weight, respectively.

Is there a way to say "use the current weight"? That is, I don't want to make the font weight of this element lighter or bolder than its surrounding text — I want it to be the same. Like this, but pretend the `span` element is really a `strong` element (because semantics):

```css
span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>This is a <span>header</span>.</p>
</header>
<footer>
  <p>This is a <span>footer</span>.</p>
</footer>
```

My goal is to use a `strong` element but without its default `font-weight` style.

Obviously `font-weight: normal` doesn't work, since as mentioned `normal` specifically corresponds to the numeric weight of 400. I tried `font-weight: initial`, but that seems to have the same effect as `font-weight: normal`.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question: The `lighter` and `bolder` keywords are *already* relative to the current font-weight (inherited from the nearest ancestor specifies a font-weight, or browser default if none was ever specified).

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: Yeah, my question was how to specify the current weight without making it lighter *or* bolder. Let me see if I can come up with a better title.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking - the current weight is simply inherited, it is what's applied unless other rules override it (or, overrule it, really). Part of the problem is that you talk about "surrounding text". There is no such thing in HTML/CSS. There's element trees, and what you show is a tree with two paragraphs that have nothing to do with each other. The spans you're showing are already the same weight as the `<p>` they're in, because of inheritance, so... what's the actual problem?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: The actual problem is not realizing that inheritance is what makes an element the same weight as its parent - hence my question coupled with the self-answer. And not everyone thinks in terms of element trees. (I do, but I've clearly had quite the brain fart here.)

Comment: they don't, which is why it's your, and my, responsibility to explain how CSS works when someone seems to not have a firm grasp of the basics of the DOM tree, and how that works in conjunction with that the "cascading" part of Cascading StyleSheets

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: Hence my answer, which I've just edited to add a bit about the element tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`font-weight` doesn't have a special keyword value for the "current weight". Instead, you use the CSS-wide `inherit` keyword to *inherit* the weight from the parent element (the element that contains the so-called "surrounding text" along with the element in question):

```css
strong {
  font-weight: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>This is a <strong>header</strong>.</p>
</header>
<footer>
  <p>This is a <strong>footer</strong>.</p>
</footer>
```

This may not be obvious to those who aren't intimately familiar with the `inherit` keyword, or CSS inheritance in general. But the reason it works is because `font-weight`, like all other font properties, is inherited by nature, and in fact the `bolder` and `lighter` keyword values are based on the inherited value. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-weight-prop):

> **bolder**
>   Specifies a bolder weight than the inherited value.
>
> **lighter**
>   Specifies a lighter weight than the inherited value.

So, it follows that one specifies the inherited value, unchanged, by using the `inherit` keyword.

The (also CSS-wide) `initial` keyword has the same effect as `normal` because the *initial value* of the `font-weight` property, as defined by the spec, is in fact `normal`. However, because `font-weight` is an inherited property, the property defaults to (for when there is no cascaded value) inheritance rather than the initial value of `normal` — setting `initial` explicitly results in a [cascaded value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascaded) of `initial`, which blocks inheritance, thereby resulting in a [computed value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#computed) of 400.

Answer (score 0):

We can also consider the value `unset` that will behave as `inherit` in case there is a value inherited from the parent element and will fall to `initial` when no value is inherited.

> If the cascaded value of a property is the `unset` keyword, then if it is an inherited property, this is treated as `inherit`, and if it is not, this is treated as `initial`. This keyword effectively erases all declared values occurring earlier in the cascade, correctly inheriting or not as appropriate for the property<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/#inherit-initial)</sup>

```css
strong {
  font-weight: unset;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>This is a <strong>header</strong>.</p>
</header>
<footer>
  <p>This is a <strong>footer</strong>.</p>
</footer>
```

Worth to note that this value is not supported within IE (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value) *(not a surprise though)*