# CSS default value of a property

Tags: css

So i am reading this book Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3 by Microsoft and there is this exercise using tables, there is a css rule to display and hide some elements but only the hidden or actually in css display:none property is working and the display:normal says its an invalid value in css.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: normal;
}
```

Is it possible that this book is actually wrong about the display:normal property or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `display`:normal` *is* invalid...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Try `display: initial`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `display: normal` is invalid.

The default value of `display` may depend on what you mean with "default".

1. [Initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-values):

   > Each property has an *initial value*, defined in the property’s
   >   definition table. If the property is not an [inherited property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-property),
   >   and the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade) does not result in a value, then the [specified
   >   value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value) of the property is its [initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value).

   The initial value of `display` is `inline`.
2. [Inherited value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-value), in case the property is inheritable

   > [Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inheritance) propagates property values from parent elements to
   >   their children. The [inherited value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-value) of a property on an element
   >   is the computed value of the property on the element’s parent element.

   `display` in not inheritable, so this is not relevant.
3. [User agents style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-origin-ua):

   > [Conforming user agents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#conformance) must apply a default style sheet (or
   >   behave as if they did). A user agent’s default style sheet should
   >   present the elements of the document language in ways that satisfy
   >   general presentation expectations for the document language (e.g., for
   >   visual browsers, the EM element in HTML is presented using an italic
   >   font). See e.g. the [HTML user agent style sheet](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints).

   In that stylesheet, browsers style some elements with `display: block`, `display: table`, etc.
4. [User style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-origin-user),

   > The user may be able to specify style information for a particular
   >   document.
5. [Author stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-origin-author)

   These are your stylesheets.

The cascade will result in the latest applicable (in fact it's more complicated because there are things like specificity, scoping and `!important`).

When you want to set some property to a default value, you can use

- [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial) (introduced in CSS Cascade 3)

  > the property’s [initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value) becomes its [specified value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value).

  Then, `display: initial` will be equivalent to `display: inline`.
- [`inherit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherit) (introduced in CSS2)

  > the [inherited value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-value) becomes the property’s [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value) and
  >   [computed values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#computed-value)

  Then, `display: inherit` will use the value of the parent element (or the initial value for the root element).
- [`unset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial) (introduced in CSS Cascade 3)

  > if it is an inherited property, this is treated as [`inherit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#valdef-all-inherit),
  >   and if it is not, this is treated as [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#valdef-all-initial).

  Since `display` is not inheritable, `display: unset` will be equivalent to `display: initial`, that is, `display: inline`.
- [`revert`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default) (introduced in CSS Cascade 4)

  When used in an author stylesheet,

  > Rolls back the cascade to the user level, so that the [specified
  >   value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#specified-value) is calculated as if no author-level rules were specified
  >   for this property.

  This is probably what you want.

Comment: 1+ Excellent answer. I didn't realize `initial` would set the value to `inline`.. that's pretty useless for the `display` property.

Comment: The `inherit` keyword was introduced in CSS2. At the time, IE was a pain point because it didn't implement it until IE8 (the CSS2-compliant release). Coincidentally, I just recently posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441499/is-there-a-way-to-say-use-the-current-font-weight-without-making-it-lighter-bo) whose answer was to use the `inherit` keyword.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: The initial value doesn't make sense to specify on every property and every element. It's only really there so that any element (even unknown elements) is guaranteed to have a computed value for every property. Otherwise, browsers would need to specify values for every property for every single element in their UA stylesheets. Which means `display: inline` for *everything* that doesn't have to be a block or a table or something else, for example.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the correction. (BTW, IE8 claiming to be fully CSS2.1 compliant is hilarious. I recognize there was a great improvement since IE7, though.)

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, its definition of "CSS2.1 compliance" was something close to "Acid2 compliance", which isn't a totally realistic benchmark. But it's better than some of Chrome's bugs, at least.